# Does delegate chaining have to start with a null Delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

In [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045), Jeffrey Richter gives the following example of delegate chaining (pg. 406):

```
internal delegate void Feedback(Int 32 value);

Feedback fb1 = new Feedback(method1);  // in the book, these methods
Feedback fb2 = new Feedback(method2);  // have different names
Feedback fb3 = new Feedback(method3); 

Feedback fbChain = null;
fbChain = (Feedback) Delegate.Combine(fbChain, fb1);
fbChain = (Feedback) Delegate.Combine(fbChain, fb2);
fbChain = (Feedback) Delegate.Combine(fbChain, fb3);
```

Why does the first call to `Delegate.Combine` have to pass in a null `Delegate`?  Here's how I would have thought it should be written:

```
Feedback fbChain = (Feedback) Delegate.Combine(fb1, fb2);
fbChain = (Feedback) Delegate.Combine(fbchain, fb3);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct - you don't have to start with a null. What `Delegate.Combine` does is return a new delegate with the invocation list of the first argument appended with the invocation list of the second argument. If one of the arguments is null it just returns the other delegate you passed in.

Also, you don't have to use `Combine` directly. You can do this:

```
Feedback fbChain = method1;
fbChain += method2;
fbChain += method3;
```

or

```
fbChain = new Feedback(method1) + new Feedback(method2) + new Feedback(method3);
```

as `+` for delegates maps onto `Combine`. This is also typechecked by the compiler, rather than having to use Delegate.Combine (which will only fail at runtime if the signatures don't match)

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771.aspx) it seems you can reduce it even further:

```
Feedback fbChain = (Feedback) Delegate.Combine(fb1, fb2, fb3);
```